# compress file using /bin/gzip with particular patterns

Tags: shell-script, rename, compression, gzip

I want to compress files individually with the particular pattern.
For example, I have directory as below :

```
/log/log1
    -/1/log2/file.1
    -/1/log2/file123
    -/1/log2/file2.1
/log/log2
    -/2/log2/file4.1
    -/2/log2/file345
    -/2/log2/file3.1
```

I want to compress all the files having extension .1 inside /log recursively.

The result will look like

```
/log/log1
    -/1/log2/file.gz
    -/1/log2/file123
    -/1/log2/file2.gz
/log/log2
    -/2/log2/file4.gz
    -/2/log2/file345
    -/2/log2/file3.gz
```

Comment: So you also need to rename the files as you go...? Otherwise `file.1` would be compressed as `file.1.gz`, etc.

Comment: And do you really have the `/log/log1/-/` and `/log/log2/-/` directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find /log -type f -name "*.1" -exec bash -c 'gzip -nc "$1" > "${1:0:-2}.gz"; rm "$1"' _ {} \;
```

`gzip` options:

- `-n` - when compressing, do not save the original file name and time stamp by default
- `-c` - write output on standard output; keep original files unchanged

`${1:0:-2}` - `bash`'s *slicing*; get filepath with the last 2 characters truncated

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
find /log -name '*.1' -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    gzip "$file" && mv -i "$file.gz" "${file%.*}.gz"
  done' sh {} +
```

We use the `gzip file && mv -i file.gz newfile` as opposed to `gzip < file > newfile && rm -f file` to benefit  from `gzip`'s ability to preserve some of the metadata into the compressed file and for `mv -i`'s better ability to deal with conflicts.